# Excel - league table, two teams on same points

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel to build a league table.
There are six teams, who place each other and can score up to 210 points each game.
They play five times over the series, total of 1050 points to be won.

As such, the league table is pretty simple and is decided by points scored. If they are level, then points conceded is the second criteria.

Using rank and index, this works fine, except when both teams have scored the same points and conceded the same points. Does anyone know how to have the league table show that Team 2 and Team 3 are both in second place in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your question, you want to know how to make your table show something like the following in the case that Teams 2 and 3 are tied in both points scored and points conceded:

```
  A         B        C      D
Place  |  Team   |  PF  |  PC   
1      |  Team1  |  300 |  60
2      |  Team2  |  250 | 110
2      |  Team3  |  250 | 110
4      |  Team4  |  120 | 180
5      |  Team5  |  100 | 260
6      |  Team6  |   30 | 330
```

To get this, you need to enter 1 in A2, and fill down the following in A3 through A7:

```
=IF(AND(C3=C2,D3=D2),A2,ROW()-ROW($A$1))
```

where A1 is the header of the Place column.